# Ng Serve Module issue

Tags: angular, .net-core

I have developed a system including a chatbot. so when now I need to open the system it shows an error in the command prompt. I tried uninstalling npm and reinstalling it too but still, it doesn't work. I have inserted a below image where you could see the error.

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XILcv.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCMSv.png)

Comment: You should paste code/error log instead of images whenever possible.

Comment: Do a proper import of `command-runner` model in the `ts` file. It seems to be `path` issue of the import

Comment: Links expire. When the link to your code expires, your question loses all value. Don't post code in links. Also, code frequently needs to be executed to find the problem. When you post images of code, you are asking people who want to help you to jump through hoops before they can actually, you know, help.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, got it fixed by below method:

**Method:**

**1.** Uninstall `nodejs`

**2.** clean your cache (C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache):

`npm cache clean --force`

**3.** delete `package-lock.json` and node `node_modules` folder

**4.** Install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/) latest version

**5.** Install latest angular cli `npm install -g @angular/cli@latest`.

**6.** Run `npm install` and `ng serve`.

For more details check [here](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/1044)

Comment: This is not a solution. None of this will work if the import paths are wrong in the `ts` file ! The error clearly shows the path of `command-runner` model is mismatching !

Comment: @SouravDutta let him try once IF it not going to help him then I surely removed this answer

Comment: @SideshIsmath please let me know if it not helpful for you